# determine pivot flick and drag is right or left in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a Pivot control in a page.

```
<controls:Pivot x:Name="pvtSearchFlights">
                <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    <toolkit:GestureListener DragCompleted="GestureListener_DragCompleted" Flick="GestureListener_Flick"   />
                </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <controls:PivotItem x:Name="pvtItemCurrent">
                    <StackPanel Height="700" Background="AliceBlue">
                    </StackPanel>
                </controls:PivotItem>
                <controls:PivotItem x:Name="pvtItemNext">
                    <StackPanel Height="700" Background="Red">
                    </StackPanel>
                </controls:PivotItem>
                <controls:PivotItem x:Name="pvtItemPrevious">
                    <StackPanel Height="700" Background="Green">
                    </StackPanel>
                </controls:PivotItem>
            </controls:Pivot>
```

Here i am able to find the whether flick is right or left by the  below code:

```
private void GestureListener_Flick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Angle > 90 && e.Angle < 270)
            {
                txtTest.Text = "right";
            }
            else 
            {
                txtTest.Text = "left";
            }
        }
```

If i drag the pivot pivot control, the pivot item is Changing but GestureListener_Flick event is not fired because it is a drag event(here it fired GestureListener_DragCompleted event). So while i am dragging also i have to find whether it is dragged to left or right?

**Here my main aim is to find the whether pivot is moved right to left or left to right?**

**How can i find whether it is dragged to left or right?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Besides the panning/dragging gesture, you would also have to solve the issue for the third way to change items: tapping the header of the next item.

Answer (score 2):

What about storing current index of Pivot and add SelectionChanged event handler and then just compare old stored index and new one from event?

If diff "new - old" is gt 0, it is to the right and if diff is lt 0 it is to the left. You have to handle special state, when old or new is 0.